# Save data input from one sheet onto successive rows in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a Macro in Excel that is assigned to a button in 'Sheet 1'. Upon clicking the button I require the data from certain cells on Sheet 1 to be logged into a row of cells in Sheet 2.

I want to be able to input data on Sheet 1 *again*, **in the same cells as before**, and then to click the button and have this new data appear in Sheet 2 on the **next row down** from before (i.e. Sheet 2 will be a kind of log of what has been entered in Sheet 1 before the button is clicked).

I have the data from Sheet 1 logging into the row on Sheet 2, and then when I click the button the data goes into the next row, but the original row empties - it isn't storing the data from before the button is clicked.

Comment: paste the rows only after the last used row -  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` will only give the last used row if there are no blank lines at the top of the sheet...